# Vectorial function representation

Tags: vectors, parametric

I'm trying to solve the following excersice:

> Given the following equations, represent by a vector function:

1. $y=x^2+1$ from $(3,10)$ to $(-1,2)$
2. $y=4-x$ with $x\in [-2,3]$
3. ${x^2\over{25}} + {y^2\over{16}} =1$ counter-clock wise from $(5,0)$

So, parameterizing, in each case with $x = t$

1. $y=t^2+1$, then $r_1=(t,t^2+1)$
2. $y=4-t$, then $r_2(t)=(t, 4-t)$
3. ${t^2\over{25}} + {y^2\over{16}} = 1 \implies y=\sqrt{16-{16\over{25}}t^2}$, then $r_3 =\left(t, \sqrt{16-{16\over{25}}t^2}\right)$

My question is: this is well done?, and what can I do with data on which the domain is defined (i.e. "from $(3,10)$ to $(-1,2)$")?

Thanks!

Comment: First, these are not "representations of functions", these are representations of the GRAPHS of these functions.  Yes, when a graph IS given by a function, y= f(x), you can represent them as (x, f(x)).  However, in 1 and 2, you have not included the limits on t that would give the  required limits on x.  And, in 3, y is NOT a function of f.  Making it one by taking  the square root restricts y to be non-negative which is not correct.  (Hint: think sin^2(t)+ cos^2(t)= 1)